# Variable Validation in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I need to know how I can vaildate a variable in Laravel. 
Until now, I only used `$request` for validation in this way.

```
$request->validate([
    'idgroup' => [
        'required',
        'numeric',
        new AdminGroupRequest,
        new MaxInvitationAdmin
    ]
]);
```

How can I use this validation code above for the following variable?

```
$idgroup = Session::get('invitation_userid');
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `Validator::make` factory function.

[Validation documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#manually-creating-validators)

```
$data = ['idgroup' => Session::get('invitation_userid')];

Validator::make($data, [
    'idgroup' => [
        'required', 'numeric', new AdminGroupRequest, new MaxInvitationAdmin
    ]
])->validate();
```